# Refresh Captcha if failed

Tags: php, captcha

I have a custom captcha created in php. I want the text on the captcha to refresh when validation fails so the user does not have to fill the form all over again.  How can i do this?

```
<?php
    if(!session_id() || session_id() == ''){
        session_start();
    }

    $captcha = "";

    for ($i=0; $i < 5; $i++) {

        $captcha .= chr(rand(97,122));

    }

    $_SESSION['captcha_code'] = $captcha;

    $dir = 'fonts/';

    $image = imagecreatetruecolor(170,60);
    $black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
    $color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 10, 10);
    $white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);

    imagefilledrectangle($image , 0 , 0 , 200 , 100 , $white);
    imagettftext($image, 30, 5 , 10 , 40 , $color , 'fonts/MacyandKaraFont.ttf' , $_SESSION['captcha_code']);

    header("Content-type: image/png");
    imagepng($image);
    // session_destroy();

 ?>
```

Html code for the captcha

```
 <div class="col-md-3">
       <img src="captcha.php" alt="" /> <br/>
             <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group">
                 <label>Enter code as seen above</label>
           <input type="text" name="code" Placeholder="Enter code as see above" class="form-control">
               <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
         </div>
    </div>

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['statement-submit'])) {

            // echo $_SESSION['captcha_code'];
            // echo $_POST['code'];
            $code = htmlentities(strip_tags(trim($_POST['code'])));

            if ($_SESSION['captcha_code'] === $code) {
?>
```

Comment: First it wouldn't make much sense as the reCaptcha is reloaded each time the page refreshes. This means that ***even if you retain the old value, reCaptcha would still not validate and thus fail.***. So whatever happens, a user would still be required to re-type the reCaptcha field. Get the drift? Why don't you use the new reCaptcha that doesn't require any text input? It may make your life a lot easier, though...

Comment: Ahhhaaa... you edited it... .Custom captcha could work... ;-) but not google's reCaptcha.... However, still **the sense in Captcha is to invalidate the previous values when things go wrong. That way, you as a programmer, are sure you are dealing with a Human Being and not a Robot....** ***that is: the values were not submitted by a robot, but Human***

Comment: I couldn't use google reCaptcha because i have about nine forms on same page, and wasn't ready to use javacript for it. All that is needed is for the text to change to a new one when validation fails

Comment: So your goal is to keep retain the same old Captcha Data even when the Page reloads, right? If yes that's possible and could be worked out. Can you confirm because your post seems to have been edited multiple times now?  :-)

Comment: My goal is to notify the user that captcha validation failed and refresh the captcha to a new one so the user does not have to submit the form before realizing the validation failed, which means filling the form all over again

Comment: Well, in that case, you might want to check out the PHP-Ajax Solution offered below.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you may use AJAX. Below is what I thought might come-in handy...

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
   // 
   // PULL-IN JQUERY FROM THE CDN.
   // IF YOU ALREADY HAVE IT LOCALLY, CHANGE THE SRC ATTRIBUTE.

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function ($) {
            $(document).ready(function(e) {
                // ASSUMING THAT THE CAPTCHA FIELD'S CLASS IS "captcha_field"
                // YOU CAN JUST USE JAVASCRIPT'S ON-BLUR EVENT TO TRIGGER THE SENDING OF A REQUEST TO THE PHP SCRIPT LIKES BELOW
                // BUT FIRST WE DECLARE A VARIABLE TO HOLD THE CAPTCHA FIELD'S JQUERY OBJECT...
                var captchaField    = $(".captcha_field");      <== CHANGE TO THE APPROPRIATE CLASS OR ID 

                // SET UP THE EVENT HANDLER FOR THE ON-BLUR AS MENTIONED ABOVE...
                captchaField.on("blur", function(evt){              
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'ajax_helper.php',     // <== POINTS TO THE VALID URL OF THE AJAX HELPER... DECIDE FOR YOURSELF...
                        dataType: "json",
                        cache: false,
                        type: "POST",
                        data: ({
                            'captcha_code'  : captchaField.val()    // <== ASSUMES THAT THE CAPTCHA FIELD HAS A CLASS CALLED captcha_field 
                        }),

                        //HANDLE THE SUCCESS CASE FOR THE AJAX CALL
                        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                            if(data){
                                // CHECK IF THE THERE WAS AN ERROR WITH THE CAPTCHA VALIDATION IN THE PHP SCRIPT 
                                if(data.error && data.error != null){
                                    // DISPLAY A WARNING MESSAGE TO THE USER TO INFORM THEM OF THE ERROR...
                                    // HERE WE USE A SIMPLE ALERT BUT YOU CAN IMPLEMENT YOUR FANCY UI...
                                    alert(data.error);
                                }else {
                                    // IF EVERYTHING WORKS FINE; YOU CAN DO WHATEVER YOU WISH HERE...
                                    // PERHAPS POST THE FORM OR JUST IGNORE THIS CLAUSE.
                                }
                            }
                        },

                        //HANDLE THE FAILURE CASE FOR THE AJAX CALL
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            console.log('The following error occured: ' + textStatus, errorThrown);
                        },

                        //HANDLE THE EVENT-COMPLETE CASE FOR THE AJAX CALL
                        complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

Create a new PHP File (call it whatever You like but I just called it ***ajax_helper.php*** here for simplicity. This File will process your AJAX Request.

**PHP:**

```
    <?php
        /**
         * 
         * AJAX HELPER
         * Filename: ajax_helper.php
         * 
         */ 

        // CHECK TO SEE THAT YOUR AJAX CALL POSTED THE captcha_code DATA TO THE AJAX HELPER SCRIPT
        if( isset($_POST['captcha_code'])  && $_POST['captcha_code'] ){
            $captcha_code       = $_POST['captcha_code'];
            // NOW, DO YOUR PROCESSING...
            // USE YOUR CAPTCHA'S LOGIC TO DETERMINE WHETHER THE CAPTCHA WAS RIGHT OR NOT
            // IN THE END YOU'D HAVE A CONDITIONAL LOGIC LIKE BELOW:

            // COMPARE THE VALUE OF THE $captcha_code TO THE VALUE STORED IN THE SESSION                
            if($captcha_code == $_SESSION['captcha_code']){
                $ajaxPayload    = array(
                    "error"     => null,
                );
            }else{
                $ajaxPayload    = array(
                    "error"     => "The entered Captcha is invalid. Please, try again.",
                );          
            }

            die( json_encode($ajaxPayload));
        }else{
            $ajaxPayload    = array(
                "error"     => "You haven't entered the Captcha. Please, enter the Capture Code.",
            ); 
            die( json_encode($ajaxPayload));

        }
```